# Contouring 2D Array with OpenCV (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, opencv

I have a simple question:

I have a 2D Array, with each 'x' and 'y' coordinate having a height 'z'. Can OpenCV be used on NumPy arrays to extract contours in Python? I've seen numerous examples with JPG, PNG etc but can't find examples with an input array.

I just want to compare the quality/suitability of the contour on DICOM arrays in my research.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: OpenCV uses numpy as the backend, so you can use the array directly as if it were an image.

Answer (score 0):

Image is simply an array. So, if you can do the same with images then obviously it's possible with the array as well. So, the answer to your question is yes. You can use the OpenCV to extract the contours from the NumPy array.